# Redirect image with parameter htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to redirect an image url to PHP only if it has a parameter "o"

Here's what I've tried, I get no error, it just loads the image.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^o=([0-9\.]+)$
RewriteRule opacity\.php?pic=%1 [L]
```

http://example.com/some/directry/image.jpg?o=0.3 > Redirects to opacity.php?pic=image.jpg?o=0.3
http://example.com/some/directry/image.jpg > No redirect

The GET variable will be between 0 and 1

Any help appreciated

Also something similar to this would work but also not working :(

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)\?o=([0-9.]+)$ opacity.php?pic=$1&o=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(o=[0-9\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*?\.jpg)$ opacity.php?pic=$1&%1 [R=301]
```

Or without testing if the ending is jpg

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(o=[0-9\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*?)$ opacity.php?pic=$1&%1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I still get no redirect. I have the .htaccess file in the same directory as the images and opacity.php Example: http://domain.com/agent/ez/assets/bg/uploads/bathroom.jpg?o=1.1 Does that change anything?

Comment: If you want to redirect replace `[L]` with `[R=301]`

Comment: Probably you also have to add RewriteBase to your htaccess when you place it in a subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

This works but I don't like it at all

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.[jpg|png|jpeg|gif] [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) opacity.php?p=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```